# From dropdown to table in Magento

Tags: html, magento, drop-down-menu, html-table

I am using Magento Community in order to develop a webshop. I am creating products with a dropdown custom option. I have been trying to change the display (HTML) of this information. Basically, I would like to display a table instead of the dropdown menu that appears currently, but I do not know how to do it. The file I have tried to edit is located in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option. What I understood is that the information is inserted using the following code:

```
<?php endif; ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="bundle_option[<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>]" value="<?php echo $_selections[0]->getSelectionId() ?>"/>
<?php else:?>
    <select onchange="bundle.changeSelection(this)" id="bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>" name="bundle_option[<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>]" class="bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?><?php if ($_option->getRequired()) echo ' required-entry' ?> bundle-option-select change-container-classname">
        <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Choose a selection...') ?></option>
    <?php foreach ($_selections as $_selection): ?>
        <?php if ($_selection->getSelectionCanChangeQty() && $this->_isSelected($_selection)): ?>
            <?php $tierPriceHtml = $this->getTierPriceHtml($_selection); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $_selection->getSelectionId() ?>"<?php if ($this->_isSelected($_selection)) echo ' selected="selected"' ?><?php if (!$_selection->isSaleable()) echo ' disabled="disabled"' ?>><?php echo $this->getSelectionTitlePrice($_selection, false) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
```

What I tried to do is to get the information while building a table, so I added some lines at the end of the  tag in order to see a table under the dropdown, with all the information, something as basic as the following lines:

```
<table class="probapifa">
    <?php foreach ($_selections as $_selection1): ?>
        <tr id="rowpifa" value="<?php echo $_selection1->getSelectionId() ?>"><?php echo $this->getSelectionTitlePrice($_selection1, false) ?></tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
```

The result is unappreciated, as I can see nothing even if I select a new option from the dropdown. Also, I can see that in the code above, it says *Choose a product* for the initial selected option, when in the product site the text that appears is *Please select*. (I read it should be edited in the CSV file, right?). So my guess is that I am not editing the right file, what should I do? I really need your help.

Comment: What is product type simple/bundle?? if simple product then product custom options are come from following locations app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view\options\type

Comment: maybe it's true but what I found in those folders is a document that basically is a script to get all the options. I enabled template hints to know where the html is defined, and it says the dropdown is defined in frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/. I checked the files over there and options may load all the products on javascript. So how could I display a table instead of a dropdown?